# sending checkbox array from js to django views

Tags: python, arrays, json, ajax, django

I'm confused about how to do it via Ajax or Json, but how can I send the selection array (curCheck) on-click to Django views and receive it as a python array

javascript

```
document.getElementById('results').addEventListener('click', function(){
    html_table = '<thead><tr><th>Currency</th><th>Amount</th><th>Symbol</th>><tr/><thead/>'
        var checkElements = document.getElementsByClassName('ch');
        for(var i =0; i< curname.length; i++){
            if (checkElements[i].checked) {
            var curChecked = curname[i];
            var JsonArr = JSON.stringify(curChecked);
            postcurChecked(JsonArr)
            html_table += '<tr><td>' + curname[i] + '</td>';
            }
}
document.getElementById('result_table').innerHTML = html_table;
},false;
```

ajax

```
function postsubChecked(curChecked) {
    $.ajax({
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/results/",
        "type": "POST",
        "data": {"checkbox": curChecked},
        "headers": { 'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')}
    })
}
```

in django

```
def currencyChecked(request): 
    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8') 
    body_unicode = body_unicode.replace('%22','') 
    print(body_unicode) json_data = json.loads(body_unicode.read())
```

I would like to see the python array print to see it is passed to the back

but I keep getting this error:
json_data = json.loads(body_unicode.read()) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: you don't need to use `request.body` and decode it, just `request.POST.get('checkbox')` should be the json string you want. And why `read()`? Just `json.loads(request.POST['checkbox'])` should do the trick.

Comment: @dirkgroten thank you so much! That totally worked. Learner here, that's why! :D

Answer (score 1):

For getting the selected checkbox values and sending as an array using ajax you can use jquery like this:

consider you have multiple checkboxes and a button.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="imageName">
<input type="checkbox" name="imageName">
.......
<button id="deletePhoto">Delete</button>
```

after selecting multiple checkbox values click on this button. On clicking the below jquery will be triggered to make an arrya of selected checkbox values.

```
//jquery for getting the selelcted checkbox values 

  $(document).on("click","#deletePhoto",function(){

    var favorite = [];//define array

    $.each($("input[name='imageName']:checked"), function(){            
        favorite.push($(this).val());
    });

    alert("Photo Selected: " + favorite.join(", "));

    if(favorite.length == 0){
      alert("Select Photo to delete");
      return false;
    }

    //ajax for deleting the multiple selelcted photos
    $.ajax({type: "GET",
    url: "/olx/deletePhotoFromEdit",
    data:{
      favorite:favorite
    },
    success: function(){
     // put more stuff here as per your requirement
    });

   }
    });

});
```

In the view you can get the array like this:

```
selected_photo = request.GET.getlist('favorite[]')
```