# How can I make actions with selected objects in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm new at Django and have some troubles with making actions with database objects, which I need to select with checkboxes.

models.py

```py
    class Scooter (models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='name')
        price = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, verbose_name='price')
        url = models.URLField(verbose_name='url')
```

views.py

```py
    class MainView(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'mainApp/index.html'
        def get(self, request):
            scooters = Scooter.objects.all().order_by('price')
            return (render(request, self.template_name, context={'scooters':scooters}))
```

and my html template is:

```html
<table class="table table-sm table-borderless table-hover table-responsive-lg">
        <caption>Перечень товаров</caption>
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col">№</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <form action="" method="post">
                {% for elem in scooters %}
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="{{ elem.num }}" name="scooter_select" value="/{{ elem.num }}">
                        <label for="scooter{{ elem.num }}"></label>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        {{ forloop.counter }}
                    </th>
                    <th scope="row">
                        <a href="{{ elem.url }}">{{ elem.name }}</a>
                    </th>
                    <td>{{ elem.price }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ elem.id }}/update" class="badge badge-warning" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Edit</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ elem.id }}/delete" class="badge badge-danger" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </form>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

So I can't understand, how can I catch selected with checkbox objects?

Comment: are you trying to submit this form or just want selected checkboxes in js ?

Comment: If you want to "catch" them on backend side then you need to add `post` method (post request handler) to your view.

Comment: Do you need to get the selelcted checkbox value in backend? If yes then I already answered for this here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55903907/sending-checkbox-array-from-js-to-django-views/55908268#55908268

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: I'm trying to apply Your answer to my code. Is it necessary to use jquery?

Comment: @ Ivan Starostin in that case I need to create NewForm for that template in forms.py?

Comment: Just follow the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#the-view